# How to create a background process in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, worker

I'm writing a web process to emulate the Connect4 board game. I have set it out using an Agile controller with seven columns and six rows with each cell referenced as c1r1 as below.

```
$scope.c1r1 = $scope.counterWhite;
$scope.c1r2 = $scope.counterWhite;
$scope.c1r3 = $scope.counterWhite;
.
.
$scope.c7r4 = $scope.counterWhite;
$scope.c7r5 = $scope.counterWhite;
$scope.c7r6 = $scope.counterWhite;
```

When the user clicks on any cell it raises an event which I want to show the counter dropping through the available cells, with code as below

```
$scope.c1r1 = $scope.counterYellow;
setTimeout(fillC1(), 1000);        
$scope.c1r1 = $scope.counterWhite; 
$scope.c1r2 = $scope.counterYellow;

setTimeout(fillC1(), 1000);        
$scope.c1r2 = $scope.counterWhite; 
$scope.c1r3 = $scope.counterYellow;

setTimeout(fillC1(), 1000);        
$scope.c1r3 = $scope.counterWhite; 
$scope.c1r4 = $scope.counterYellow;

setTimeout(fillC1(), 1000);        
$scope.c1r4 = $scope.counterWhite; 
$scope.c1r5 = $scope.counterYellow;

setTimeout(fillC1(), 1000);        
$scope.c1r5 = $scope.counterWhite; 
$scope.c1r6 = $scope.counterYellow;
```

When I run it nothing happens and the counter just appears at the bottom so I need a thread to make it work properly but as JavaScript doesn't do threading I wondered if there was another answer like Web Workers.

Comment: Dude, use arrays. All these numbered variables... Yikes

Comment: Thanks for the comment but if you can't answer the question please don't bother, Dude!

Comment: I'm very tempted to remove my answer now...

Comment: @user616076: There's exactly ***zero*** reason to be rude.

Comment: *"When I run it nothing happens and the counter just appears at the bottom so I need a thread to make it work properly"* No, you don't. *"but as JavaScript doesn't do threading"* Yes, it does, in several environments, including browsers. *"I wondered if there was another answer like Web Workers."* And that's how, in the browser environment, but you don't need or want them for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the way you set up your cells is part of the problem.

Instead of that load of `$scope.cXrY` variables, use arrays:

```
$scope.cells = [];
var x, y;
for(x = 0; x < 7; x ++){
    $scope.cells[x] = [];
    for(y = 0; y < 6; y ++){
        $scope.cells[x][y] = $scope.counterWhite;
    }
}
```

There you go, all your cells in *one* variable.
Instead of `$scope.c2r4`, you'd use `$scope.cells[2][4]`.

Now, for the counter going over the cells:

```
function iterateOverCells(){
    fillC1()

    $scope.cells[x][y] = $scope.counterWhite; // Make the previous cell white

    x++;        // Get next cell position
    if(x >= 7){
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }

    $scope.cells[x][y] = $scope.counterYellow; // Current cell yellow
    if(x < 7 && y < 6)                         // If we're not at the last cell
        setTimeout(iterateOverCells, 1000);    // Go to the next cell in 1 second
}

var x = 0, y = 0;
$scope.cells[x][y] = $scope.counterYellow; // Make the first cell yellow
setTimeout(iterateOverCells, 1000);        // Next cell in 1 second
```

Comment: Sorry for the earlier comment, it was unecessary. Thank you for your reply it really helped, thank you.

Comment: Ah, okay. So, did this answer your question?

Comment: I'm just putting it together now but I'm hopeful it will do the job. I'll update this shortly, thanks again for your help with this.

Comment: Thank you Cerbrus that worked, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

Web Workers don't have access to the DOM, they are for calculations. I'm not sure why you want to use a background thread, but here's how you can do it:

Let's assume you wrote a script with your background code, which posts messages when it's done with stuff (will get back to that in a sec:

```
function doWork() {
    postMessage("did something");
    setTimeout(doWork, 2000);
}
doWork();
```

Now, check that the browser supports web workers, create one, and listen on the messages published from it:

```
if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
    executer = new Worker("background.js");
}
executer.onmessage = function(event){
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = event.data;
};
```

When you're done with it, you can remove it like so:
`executer.terminate();`

Comment: Web workers aren't the solution to the OP's problem. His problem isn't in threading.